# Use custom formatting and specific highlighting of dates in material date-picker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

Both specific dates formatting and special localization work. However, if I try to use both at the same time, it fails. Why?

Here an example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5g1xbg

The error I get is:

> ERROR
>   Error: d.getDate is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **new Date**, because it isn't a date-object.

Move the css to the **global css file**, because the css is capsultated to it's own component and the datepicker is in a child component

```
dateClass = (d: any) => {
    const date = new Date(d).getDate();

    // Highlight the 1st and 20th day of each month.
    return (date === 1 || date === 20) ? 'example-custom-date-class' : undefined;
  }
```

Comment: Care to explain why?

Comment: Ok makes sense up to the point, where this examples works: https://stackblitz.com/angular/oegvyjvgnyk?file=app%2Fdatepicker-date-class-example.css . Why do I need to move it now and in this example you don't?

Comment: @rst The difference is, that they have set the ViewEncapsulation= none (encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None). When the ViewEncapsulation is none, then the css in the component is no longer capsulated.

In the example the class 'example-custom-date-class' is probably also be defined at another location (i dont know where), because when you remove the class from the css, the days 1 and 20 are marked anyway. 

My suggestion would be that you rename the css class. So it will works

Comment: I just checked that and it appears to be a stackblitz issue. If I mirror that particular problem locally, the formatting vanishes if you remove the css.